# Consumption of a REST web service using URLConnection

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to consume a RESTFUL web service using Java(HttpURLConnection and InputStream).I am able to print the response using BufferedReader, but it returns a response header as well and the format is causing issues to convert it to a Java POJO.

I tried using a URLConnection and then retrieving the input stream and passing it to the ObjectMapping(provided by Jackson)

```
   final URL url = new URL("url");
   final HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   uc.setRequestMethod("GET");
   final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   MyData myData = objectMapper.readValue(uc.getInputStream(), MyData.class);
```

Error Message : "No content to map due to end-of-input\n"

Comment: give complete code

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment.However I feel I have included the minimal section to replicate the problem.Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: Try adding `objectMapper.configure(Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, true);`. Seems like you are not closing your one of your stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot.However due to feel it will remove the request header problem as well.

Comment: final URL url = new URL("url") or  final URL url = new URL(url); ?

Comment: The "url" is a reference to the actual URL.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you don't show where you actually read the data and where you declared and filled your `output` variable. As code is now it seems to be the incorrect reading from your rest service. But instead of writing your own code to read fro rest url I would suggest to use the 3d party library  that does it for you. Here is few suggestions: [Apache Http Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html), [OK Http client](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) and finally my favorite - MgntUtils Http Client (library written and maintained by me) Here is the [HttpClient javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html), Here is the link to The latest [Maven artifacts for MgntUtils library](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) and here [MgntUtils Github link](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) that contains library itself with sources and javadoc. Choose some Http Client and read the content using that client and then you can use the content.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments.I have updated my code snippet to include the right variable.It is actually input stream retrieved from the connection object.Please let me know what could have gone wrong.

Comment: Several things could have gone wrong. I would suggest that you separate reading content from your REST service and then parsing it to JSON. it would make it cleaner and easier to debug. It seems that your problem occurs while you are reading your content. So first make sure you read your content and once you manage to read then parse it. I still suggest that you use 3d party library to read your content. Makes it cleaner and more reliable